# Groovy's classX.metaClass.getProperty in scala

Tags: scala, groovy, dsl, metaclass

Is there anything equivalent to Groovy's remarkable SomeClass.metaClass.getProperty function in scala? This would be very helpful in making domain specific languages. For example, I could then say: `val x = SomeClass(); x.arbitraryPropertyName` rather than `x.get("arbitraryPropertyName")` or `x("arbitraryPropertyName")`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your description, this feature sounds like Scala's `Dynamic`. From the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/Dynamic.html),

> A marker trait that enables dynamic invocations. Instances x of this
>   trait allow calls x.meth(args) for arbitrary method names meth and
>   argument lists args. If a call is not natively supported by x, it is
>   rewritten to x.applyDynamic("meth", args).

That is, if your class extends `Dynamic`, then calls of the form `x.arbitraryPropertyName` get translated to `x.applyDynamic("arbitraryPropertyName")`, and of course you get to define the behavior of `applyDynamic`.